# The grep implementation from 'The Practice of Programming'

Tags: grep

I was going through the [`grep.c`](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ebwk/tpop.webpage/grep.c) file (at [https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/tpop.webpage/grep.c](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ebwk/tpop.webpage/grep.c)) from Kernighan & Pike's book [The Practice of Programming](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ebwk/tpop.webpage).

If I search for regexp
`^c*`
in a file which contains nothing but
`d`
it will send these to `match()` function which will send ("c*", "d") to `matchhere` function.
`matchhere` sends ('c', "\0", "d") to `matchstar` which in turn sends ("\0", "d") to `matchhere` function. This will return 1 to the main `grep()` function

Where am I taking the values incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning 1 is the correct answer. The regular expression `^c*` matches zero or more copies of `c` at the beginning of a line, and a file containing `d` certainly matches that; in fact, *every* line of every file will match that.

Comment: thank you.
My RegEx concepts were not clear.
should understand them correctly first of all.